# combined use of accents, indices, and superscripts

Tags: accents, superscripts

I would like to combine accents, indices, and superscripts, but I am a bit confused :)

Regarding `x_k`, I want that `x_k^\top` has the `k` at the same vertical position. The solution `{x_k}^\top` is sufficient for me, apart from the fact that the `\top` is positioned further to the right, but I can live with it.

When adding a `\hat` accent to my `x`, the above solution does not work any more. Why??

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
    without accent:
    \begin{equation}
        x_k\quad x_k^\top\quad {x_k}^\top
    \end{equation}
    with accent:
    \begin{equation}
        \hat{x}_k\quad \hat{x}_k^\top\quad {\hat{x}_k}^\top
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Can someone perhaps explain this to me?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general facts about TeX:

1. when there is a superscript, the subscript is *always* moved down;
2. depending on the size of the superscript, the subscript could be moved further down;
3. constructions such as `\hat{x}_{k}` and `{\hat{x}_{k}}` are completely equivalent, because by rule the braces around an **Acc** atom (something with a math accent attached) are stripped off.

Regarding typesetting, I'd avoid things such as `{x_{k}}^{\top}`, because the superscript is too far away from the symbol.

What would I do? If I need to typeset “the transpose of *x<sub>k</sub>* multiplied by *x<sub>k</sub>*” I'd resort to

```
x_{k}^{T}x_{k}^{}
```

with a dummy superscript, but with “the vector *x<sub>k</sub>*” I'd just use `x_{k}`. Personally, I'd not use `\top` for the transpose, but I acknowledge it's frequently used.

If you want to automate the lower placement of subscripts, you can use `subdepth`. (Not that I recommend it.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subdepth}

\begin{document}
without accent:
\begin{equation}
  x_{k}\quad x_{k}^{\top}\quad {x_{k}}^{\top}
\end{equation}

with accent:
\begin{equation}
  \hat{x}_{k}\quad \hat{x}_{k}^{\top}\quad {\hat{x}_{k}}^{\top}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want the detached `\top`, the last item should be

```
{{}\hat{x}_{k}}^{\top}
```

but the output is not what I'd like to get.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the kind and helpful response, wow! :)
Can you explain why you prefer ^T instead of ^\top? Is it just your intuition, or are there specific reasons for that?

Comment: @Annika Just personal preference: `\top` usually means something completely unrelated to matrices.

Comment: and what about ^\intercal?

Comment: @Annika Even worse, but that's up to your taste. I'd recommend defining a command, say `\newcommand{\tp}{\top}` and use `^{\tp}` for the transpose, so you can experiment with different choices without changing the code in the document, but only in the definition.

Comment: That's a fantastic idea! Thank you so much, I'll do it exactly like that :)

Answer (score 0):

For subscript and superscript I suggest to use the curly brackets `{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    without accent:
    \begin{equation}
        x_{k}\quad x_{k}^{{\top}}\quad {x_{k}}^{\top}
    \end{equation}
    with accent:
    \begin{equation}
        \hat{x}_{k}\quad \hat{x}_{k}^{{\top}}\quad {\hat{x}_{k}}^{\top}\quad \hat{x}_{{k}}^{\top}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) If I understand you correctly, would you then accept that the index k shifts further downwards?

Comment: @Annika I see that the index k shifts further downwards only with without accent in 3th case.