The height of the superscript term is too large
I entered the following code in latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section{TEST}
$\dot{\boldsymbol{\xi}}^{err}_{IC}$
\end{document}

After compiling, I find that the superscript height is too large.

But I want this result:


does this help?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711715/15036

I think what you claim that you want looks too cramped. For reference, this is how it comes out in ConTeXt.

You could  resort to \dot{\boldsymbol{\xi}}_{IC}^{\lower2pt\hbox{$\scriptstyle err$}} but there must be a "cleaner" solution for getting the superscript to ignore the height of the accent.

Nice MWE, by the way.

(I've decided to simplify the answer so that it's no longer necessary to insert a typographic strut, via a \vphantom directive, in order to obtain a fix.)
I assume that you want the superscript term to be placed to the right of base term as if the \dot{...} decoration weren't there.
The \boldsymbol macro -- as provided by the amsmath package -- has a few shortcomings. You have (re)discovered one of them when you ran $\dot{\boldsymbol{\xi}}^{err}_{IC}$. Fortunately, there's an easy fix: In addition to loading the amsmath package, load the bm package as well. Among many other things, the bm package runs the instruction
\let\boldsymbol\bm

Importantly, the \bm macro (provided, unsurprisingly, by the bm package) works just fine in the sense that the superscript terms in $\dot{\bm{\xi}}^{err}_{IC}$ and $\bm{\xi}^{err}_{IC}$ are now at the same (correct) height.
Two additional comments:

You should also replace err with \mathrm{err} and IC with \mathit{IC}. The latter recommendation is based on the assumption that "IC" is the name of a variable rather than the product of variables named "I" and "C".

The main recommendation, viz., to load the bm package, is based on the implicit assumption that you're using pdfLaTeX to compile your document. If, instead, you use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile your document, the recommendation needs to be modified as follows: (a) load the unicode-math package (and don't load the bm package) and (b) use \symbf instead of \boldsymbol to generate a bold version of \xi. I.e., you should write $\symbf{\xi}^{\mathrm{err}}_{\mathit{IC}}$; of course, you could also write $\symbf{\xi}^{\symup{err}}_{\symit{IC}}$.


The following code runs correctly under pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, and XeLaTeX.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex % pdfLaTeX is in use
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}
   \newcommand{\bxi}{\bm{\xi}} % handy shortcut macro
\else % either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX is in use
   \usepackage{unicode-math} % no need to load 'amsmath' or 'amssymb'
   \let\mathrm\symup
   \let\mathit\symit
   \newcommand{\bxi}{\symbf{\xi}} % handy shortcut macro
\fi

\begin{document}
$\dot{\bxi}^{\mathrm{err}}_{\mathit{IC}} \quad
      \bxi ^{\mathrm{err}}_{\mathit{IC}}$
\end{document}


It works, thanks!

It seems that the cause of the superscript being so high is a combo of bolding, the ascender on the character and the decoration (making it higher still). Compare $\dot{b}^2$ with $\dot{\textbf{b}}^2$. Is it really correct for the superscript for the bold b to be higher than the one for the ordinary b?

@RosieF - I don't believe it's appropriate to use \textbf in math mode. For sure, if one replaces $\dot{\textbf{b}}$ with $\dot{\mathbf{b}}$, the issue of the excessive height of the ^2 term vanishes immediately. Put differently, TeX can "see through" the combined effects of \dot and \mathbf -- but not those of \dot and \textbf -- when it comes to determining where to place the subsequent superscript term.

@Mico Trouble with that is that \mathbf fails with Charter, even though Charter has bold.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign} % Use font Charter for both text and maths
\begin{document}
I need $\textbf{A}$, not $\mathbf{A}$.
\end{document}

@RosieF - Your claim that "\mathbf fails with Charter" may not be correct -- at least when one compiles one's document with a reasonably up-to-date TeX distribution. (I employ MacTeX2024.) For sure, if I have \usepackage[charter]{mathdesign} in the preamble, then $\dot{\mathbf{b}}^{\mathrm{err}}$ and $\mathbf{b}^{\mathrm{err}}$ both work -- and they both place the superscript term at the correct height. In contrast, $\dot{\textbf{b}}^{\mathrm{err}}$ continues to place the superscript term much too high. Which TeX distribution do you use, and when did you last update it?

@Mico MiKTeX 22.3. In May 2022, I tried to run some examples suggested in some other thread in TeX.SE, but got problems. Apparently some of these are due to my Miktex installation being out of date. So I uninstalled it and installed the latest, but it was so hard getting TeX back up and running that I'm generally reluctant to reinstall.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@RosieF - I can only recommend that you bring your MikTeX distribution up to date. If that's not feasible, then do learn how to use an online service such as Overleaf to compile your LaTeX documents.

\dot{\bm{\xi}}^}{\mathrm{err}} is almost certainly a syntax error

@egreg - Good eye! Let me fix this right away.

@Mico Maybe you know that, due to unfortunate circumstances, I have no access to a computer for the moment, but ^} was striking.

@egreg - I'm afraid I wasn't aware of these circumstances, and I certainly hope they change for the better soon. Anyway, I'm grateful that you spotted the typo and brought it to my attention. I'm currently contemplating if I should re-write my answer to streamline the advice I give: Instead of inserting a \vphantom between the base and exponent terms, just load the bm package under pdfLaTeX. Would you agree?

@Mico If I had been in front of a computer, I’d have first tried \dot{\bm{\xi}}^{sup}_{sub} with a good expectation about the outcome.

@egreg - The modified and simplified answer is half as long as the earlier one. :-)
